# Convert C# classes to Json

Tags: c#, json

How do i serialize multiple c# classes to one json string using . Be able to make the variables in the json data hold values that can change

string outputJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject();

i have the following classes

```
 public class Rootobject
    {
    public string Number { get; set; }
        public string RequestedDeviceType { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryMethod { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public Contacts Contacts { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public bool OverrideData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contacts
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string VIN { get; set; }
        public string MakeModelCode { get; set; }
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int YearOfInitialRegistration { get; set; }
        public string MotorType { get; set; }
        public bool OverrideData { get; set; }
    }

}
```

They must serialize to the following structure of json structure and i must be able to capture user input and set the values into json file

```
{
  "Number": "xTest",
  "RequestedDeviceType": "XXXX",
  "DeliveryMethod": "XXXX",
  "Customer": {
    "Contacts": {

      "FirstName": "John",
      "Name": "Doe",
      "Email": "mail@demo.com",
      "City": "Harare",
      "Address": "XXXXX",
      "MobilePhone": "00000000"

    },
    "Name": "Peter Chaneta",
    "Number": "4567865678",
    "OverrideData": true
  },
  "Vehicle": {
    "VIN": "weryts55444554",
    "MakeModelCode": "34010",
    "LicensePlate": "SS 100 GP",
    "Make": "RANGE ROVER",
    "Model": "SPORT",
    "YearOfInitialRegistration": 2016,
    "MotorType": "Petrol",
    "OverrideData": true
  }
}
```

Comment: `string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourobject);` does that?!? The json representation reflects your class composition, that's the job

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing you are using JSON.net.
If not you can get it over the Nuget-Packet Manager.

You called your class "Contacts" are you wanting to have more than one contact? If yes, you might want to use a List on the RootObject.

Now if you use:

```
var data = new Rootobject();
var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

You have all your data in a string as requested. From here you could write it to a file.
If you want to change the data and read it again you would use something along this:

```
Rootobject data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(dataString);
```

Now you could display the data somewhere or could change it through any input controls. (Website / Windows Form / XAML / Console ...)

Any other things you could find at the official documentation for json.net (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Otherwise your question is way too generic.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `JSON.Net` you can also use one from `System.Web.Extensions` namespace:

```
using System.Web.Extensions;


public string SerializeClassToJSON(object baseClass)
{
    var jSerializer = new JavascriptSerializer();
    var jsonString = jSerializer.Serialize(baseClass);

    return jsonString;
}
```